# Simulating std::forward with std::forward_as_tuple

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, forwarding

Let's say I use `std::forward_as_tuple` to store the arguments of a function call in a tuple

```
auto args = std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
```

And then I pass this tuple by lvalue reference to a function that wants to invoke a function `foo()` with some of the arguments in `args` as determined by another `std::integer_sequence`.  I do it with `std::move()` like so

```
template <typename TupleArgs, std::size_t... Indices>
decltype(auto) forward_to_foo(TupleArgs&& args, 
                              std::index_sequence<Indices...>) {
    return foo(std::get<Indices>(std::move(args))...);
}
```

And this would work because the rvalue qualified version of `std::get<std::tuple>` return `std::tuple_element_t<Index, tuple<Types...>>&&` which is an identity transformation of the reference-ness of the `std::tuple_element_t<Index, tuple<Types...>>` because of reference collapsing with the `&&`.

So if `std::tuple_element_t<Index, tuple<Types...>>` evaluates to `T&` the returned type would be `T& &&` which is just `T&`.  Similar reason for when `std::tuple_element_t<Index, tuple<Types...>>` returns `T&&` and `T`

Am I missing something?  Are there some cases where this would fail?

Comment: Well, `TupleArgs& args` should be `TupleArgs args` or `TupleArgs&& args` if you are moving from it.  Anything else makes it very opaque at the point of call that the object being passed in is mutated.

Comment: @Yakk right, that is something to consider, it's probably better as a forwarding reference.  Passing it by value would just create a copy of the underlying references (which is also fine I guess)

Comment: And now it should be a `std::forward<TupleArgs>` instead of a `move` as `TupleArgs&&` doesn't have to be an rvalue ref.  ;)  (if it is an rvalue ref, the foward does the right thing anyhow.  The idea is to make code correctness as local a property as reasonable)

Comment: @Yakk I think `std::forward` might not do the right thing, if for example `std::tuple_element_t` is a `T&&` and the forward results in an lvalue reference, then the `std::tuple_element_t<>&& &` would result in `T&` which is not what I want.

Comment: But it is correct if the incoming tuple was reused.  It is only valid to move from an rvalue reference member of a tuple if you also promise not to reuse the tuple itself in another context!

Comment: @Yakk I guess that's a readability problem with `forward_as_tuple` and forwarding the internal member I guess :(, making `TupleArgs` a value parameter would just hide the problem I feel like, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template <typename TupleArgs, std::size_t... Indices>
decltype(auto) forward_to_foo(TupleArgs&& args, 
                          std::index_sequence<Indices...>) {
  return foo(std::get<Indices>(std::forward<TupleArgs>(args))...);
}
```

This is the correct implementation.

Use should look like:

```
auto tuple_args = std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
forward_to_foo( std::move(tuple_args), std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(args)>{} );
```

there are a few differences here.

First, we take by forwarding reference, not by lvalue reference.  This lets the caller provide rvalue (prvalue or xvalue) tuples to us.

Second, we *forward* the tuple into the `std::get` call.  This means we only pass `get` an rvalue reference *if the tuple was moved into us*.

Third, we move into `forward_to_foo`.  This ensures the above does the right thing.

Now, imagine if we wanted to call `foo` twice.

```
auto tuple_args = std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
auto indexes = std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(args)>{};
forward_to_foo( tuple_args, indexes );
forward_to_foo( std::move(tuple_args), indexes );
```

we don't have to touch `forward_to_foo` at all, and we never move from any of the `args` more than once.

With your original implementation, any calls to `forward_to_foo` silently move from `TupleArgs` rvalue references or values without any indication at the call-site that we are destructive on the first parameter.

Other than that detail, yes that emulates forwarding.

---

Myself I'd just write a `notstd::apply`:

```
namespace notstd {
  namespace details {
    template <class F, class TupleArgs, std::size_t... Indices>
    decltype(auto) apply(F&& f, TupleArgs&& args, 
                      std::index_sequence<Indices...>) {
      return std::forward<F>(f)(std::get<Indices>(std::forward<TupleArgs>(args))...);
    }
  }
  template <class F, class TupleArgs>
  decltype(auto) apply(F&& f, TupleArgs&& args) {
    constexpr auto count = std::tuple_size< std::decay_t<TupleArgs> >{};
    return details::apply(
      std::forward<F>(f),
      std::forward<TupleArgs>(args),
      std::make_index_sequence< count >{}
    );
  }
}
```

then we do:

```
auto tuple_args = std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
auto call_foo = [](auto&&...args)->decltype(auto){ return foo(decltype(args)(args)...); };
return notstd::apply( call_foo, std::move(tuple_args) );
```

which moves the tricky bit into `notstd::apply`, which attempts to match the semantics of `std::apply`, which lets you replace it down the road with a more standard bit of code.

Comment: But when the tuple is an lvalue, and one tuple element is `T&&`, not forwarding the tuple to `get<>` will result in `T&` which might create a copy, etc.  Or do you mean that that should be left as a result of not moving the args to the function in the first place?  That would make sense idk

Comment: And that is proper if the tuple is an lvalue.  An lvalue tuple is stating that the caller may reuse the tuple later (as you can see in my call `foo` twice example).  In this case, moving from arguments is *wrong* in the first call.  The second call I make the promise not to care about the state of the tuple, and hence `move` from it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did you introduce the lambda wrapper for `foo()` in your new example?

Comment: @Curious `foo` could have overloads.  You cannot pass an overloaded function name as an object without picking an overload to use.